# Turn off dotted lines in plot.ecdf()

Tags: r, plot, ecdf

Plotting an `ecdf` object in R produces a nice empirical distribution function. E.g:

```
x = seq(1,10,1)
ecdf1 = ecdf(x)
plot(ecdf1,verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE)
```

However, the default behavior produces a figure with horizontal dotted lines at 0 and 1. I don't see an option to turn off this behavior in `plot.ecdf()` or in the underlying call to `plot.stepfun()`. Right now, I'm literally drawing a white line overtop the dotted lines.

Surely there's a way to turn off drawing these dotted lines?

[image: ecdf figure]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
plot(ecdf1,verticals=T, do.points=F,col.01line = NULL)
```

[image]

**Reasoning**: I used `getAnywhere("plot.ecdf")` and found the line `abline(h = c(0, 1), col = col.01line, lty = 2)`. That's the cause. Since it uses `col.01line` as its input for color, we simply set the color to `NULL`.

Comment: Good work, although sometimes you can just read the help page. In base-graphics  the argument to a `col` parameter can also be "transparent".

Comment: Thanks, and nice explanation on how you found the solution! Not sure how I missed that one.